# Odoo's backing up database using pg_dump, Odoo's UI command being used

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I've been studying how to use pg_dump and creating a batch file in order to backup the database of my PostgreSQL since the pgAgent is not appearing on the pgAdmin 3 that Odoo installed on my machine. We all know that there's a method in backing up the database in it's UI at 'http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager'. I was able to backup using pg_dump but it's giving me a file which is 300% the size of backing up the normal way. Is there anyone who knows the command (pg_dump) where i can output the same size and file just as the Odoo's UI does?

Here is my batch file:

```
cd\
cd "Program Files\Odoo 9.0-20161004\PostgreSQL\bin"

@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
set dbname=WHpingcon_%fullstamp%

pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 --format c --file "C:/%dbname%.sql" -U openpg --inserts sample
```

I used `'--inserts'` because i also need the whole data of database and restore it the normal way (UI). Everytime i remove '--inserts' it's giving me an error when i'm restoring it. i checked the file and it does not escape special characters. Thanks all!

Comment: why not use postgresql's built in replication methods instead?

Comment: I'm new to postgresql. Can you elaborate what you are trying to say? What i only know is pgAdmin's pgAgent but it's not available on my app.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/high-availability.html

Comment: Well what i'm trying to do is a scheduled backup automatically. Thanks for the reply tho!

Comment: that's an inferior method. postgresql replication is the way to go.